# PayPal Express Checkout with PayPal API certificate

Tags: api, paypal-express, ce-1.9.2.0

I have to integrate PayPal Express Checkout. By API signature it is working but with API Certificate it is not working and always showing error "Unable to communicate with PayPal Gateway".

Please give some solution for this.

Comment: Interesting, can you explain a bit more about your setup? Is this a local/dev machine or a live shop? How did you obtain the data/certificate? Via the "Get credentials from PayPal" button in the payment method configuration? Is there any other error in the system.log or exception.log?

Comment: I am doing it on live site, SSL verification off, Sandbox set to No, I have directly got certificate from PayPal not via "Get credentials from PayPal" button.

Comment: In log file m not getting any error or return data from PayPal.